# rails before_action dilemma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, controller

now only `current_user` can edit his own account, but only `admin` can delete account. Don't know how to give permission to admin to edit users because `current_user` function is blocking it.

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:index, :destroy]

...

private

...

    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user 
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add check for admin.

```
def correct_user 
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless (current_user?(@user) || current_user.admin?)
end
```

Comment: don't know why but still directing me to root url when I try to edit

Comment: my mistake :( remove ! from current_user.admin?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not define a new method that returns true for correct user or admin?

```
# Confirms an admin or user.
def admin_or_correct_user
  unless current_user.admin? || current_user?(@user)
    redirect_to(root_url) 
  end
end
```